# itext7 pdfHtml Xamarin.Forms 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: assembly'

Tags: xamarin.forms, itext7, pdfhtml

When trying to generate a pdfHtml report in Xamarin.Forms using a .netStandard2 project, the exception `System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Prameter name: assembly`.

[image]

This is the code that is run:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var resourceName = "Data.test.html";

using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
using (FileStream pdfDest = File.Open(targetPath, FileMode.Create))
{
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
    HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(result, pdfDest, converterProperties);
}
```

The code works, when run in a .net6 console application.

Comment: Please do not post code or errors as images

Answer (score 0):

You could check the **resourceName**. Please refer to [Xamarin.Forms Can not Read Text file from Resources Returned Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722951/xamarin-forms-can-not-read-text-file-from-resources-returned-null). One way to get the resourceName of all the project is  using:

```
assembly.GetManifestResourceNames() //get all resource

var resourcePath = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
        .Single(str => str.EndsWith("filename.html"));  // get your html resource
```

Also remember to set the *build action* of the file to **EmbeddedResource**.

Hope it works for you.